# Questions about negative binomial distribution

Tags: estimation, negative-binomial-distribution, robust

1) I know that my data is NB distributed. But also I know that it has several outliers (probably, zeros and extremely big numbers). How can I estimate NB?

I found the trick answered [here, on CV site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56402/detecting-outliers-in-count-data), and I agree that it is reasonable, but are there more efficient strategies? For example, for some NB simulations too many points do not satisfy the criteria $\sqrt{(x \in X)} > med(\sqrt{(X)}) + 3$. Can I use package [alphaOutlier](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/alphaOutlier/alphaOutlier.pdf) in an iterative way to exclude outliers? Actually, it works...Is there something REALLY wrong?

```
  install.packages("alphaOutlier")
  library("alphaOutlier")
  s=100
  m=100
  vect <- rnbinom(100, size=s, mu=m)
  vect <- c(vect, 1000)
  vect <- c(vect, 1000)
  vect <- c(vect, 1)
  vect <- c(vect, 1)
  distr <- fitdistr(vect, "Negative Binomial")
  estim_s <- distr$estimate["size"]
  estim_m <- distr$estimate["mu"]
  out <- aout.nbinom(vect, param=c(estim_s, estim_s / (estim_s + estim_m)), alpha=0.05 / length(vect))
  while(length(which(out$is.outlier == "TRUE")) > 0) {
    vect <- vect[which(out$is.outlier == "FALSE")]
    distr <- fitdistr(vect, "Negative Binomial")
    estim_s <- distr$estimate["size"]
    estim_m <- distr$estimate["mu"]
    out <- aout.nbinom(vect, param=c(estim_s, estim_s / (estim_s + estim_m)), alpha=1 / length(vect))
  }
  out
```

**Solved:** 2) I know that $\xi \sim NB(r,p)$. Can I say something about $r,p$ of ``$2 \xi$'', i.e., when the process has double intensity? I mean, for Poisson I can make some conclusions of $Pois(2 \lambda)$ when I have $Pois(\lambda)$. Can I do the same trick for $NB$?

Comment: About Q2: The distribution of $2\xi$ is $\mathrm{NB}(2r,p)$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054048/negative-binomial-distribution-sum-of-two-random-variables).

Comment: It is the best news I've heard since the New Year. Thank you very much.