# Making boxplots of hourly data in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

I have air temperature measurements from two fixed locations measured at hourly intervals. The code below is a random set of numbers used to represent the format of my data:

```
set.seed(1)
RandData <- rnorm(8760*2,sd=10)
Locations <- rep(c('UK','France'),each=8760)

Date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("1991-01-01 00:00"), 
              to=as.POSIXct("1991-12-31 23:00"), length=8760)

Final <- data.frame(Loc = Locations,
                    Doy = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%j")),
                    Tod = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%H")),
                    Temp = RandData)
```

I can plot the variation in temperature as a funtion of day of year with the following code:

```
require(lattice)
xyplot(Temp~Doy | Loc, data = Final, col = "black", type = "l")
```

This would show the annual pattern of the data. However, what I would like to do is to produce boxplots of the variation in temperature for different times of the day. So, for the example above I would like two figures, one for each country and each figure should be composed of box plots showing the variation in temperature at 00:00, 01:00... and so on, referring to Final$Tod. How can this be achieved?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Final, aes(x = as.factor(Tod), y = Temp)) + geom_boxplot()  + facet_wrap(~ Loc)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
library(robustbase)
adjbox(Final$Temp[Final$Loc=="UK"]~Final$Tod[Final$Loc=="UK"])
```

Boxplots are a visualization tool, so i'll give you a visual advice. 
What you have is essentially [functional data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_boxplot) so you 
want (for visualization reasons) to use a box-plot tool that 
acknowledges that. Try the [functional boxplot](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sunwards/Publication/fbplot.html) function in the 
fda package.

Comment: Yes (+1), this is much easier to visualize than the many box plots as well. I will have to re-read to make sure, but I believe Tukey (in EDA) actually suggests to not use the box's like this anyway, but to connect the lines for the summary statistics (see [this similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18826/1036)). Of course using functional boxplots is a better replacement for identifying outliers as well.