# Can Chauvenet's criterion be used with non-normal data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, outliers

Can I use [Chauvenet's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvenet%27s_criterion) on set of observations where a normal distribution cannot be assumed?

Comment: Surely, you are aware that robust statistics and outlier detection has improved a lot in the last *150 years*. Is there any reason you are using this test?

Comment: @user603, thanks soo much! I am reading "An Introduction to Error Analysis: The Study of Uncertainties in Physical Measurements" of John R. Taylor (chapter 6) and I thinked Chauvenet's criterion can be use only on set of observations where a normal distribution can be assumed!

Comment: You might want to ditch Chauvenet altogether. Look perhaps at [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/is-there-a-boxplot-variant-for-poisson-distributed-data/13429#13429) for a way to identify univariate outliers without assuming *symmetry*.

Comment: @user603, ah.. more interesting..!! thanks a lot for hint! ;)