# How to work on this one-sided distribution ?

Tags: distributions, outliers, skewness

I'd like to know if there are any model, any known distribution which fits on this one below : 
[image]

[image]

Here are the statistics I've got :

```
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.000    2.000    4.000    9.219    8.000 6277.000
```

The purpose is to create an outlier detection, a bit like box plot, but I think that box plot is only suited for symmetric distribution.

Comment: Please do not use answers to "bump" your question. Answers are meant to answer the question.

Comment: there's not enough info to answer your question. looks like poisson. try QQ plots

Comment: @Aksakal It's far too dispersed to be Poisson.  Christopher, you might find some ideas at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13086.